# How to make a path to a Web Api method

Tags: image, file, asp.net-web-api, path, getfiles

I want to write a method that can dynamically send a folder path and then send an image file to the client.

> The code is static

```
[Route("GetImageFile/{id}")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetImageFile(string id)
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"d:\gate\images\" + @"\" + id + ".jpg", 
                 System.IO.FileMode.Open);
    response.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = 
                 new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
    return response;
}
```

**Now I want to take the episode** `@ "d: \ gate \ images \"` **dynamically from the client.**

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Now I want to take the episode @ "d: \ gate \ images \" dynamically from the client. - @IpsitGaur

Comment: You can simply take that from a parameter as answered below but it is not preferred way of doing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think taking second action argument from uri will solve your issue, but such approach, however, isn't fully restful. Example:

```
[Route("GetImageFile/{id}")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetImageFile([FromUri] string id, [FromUri] string searchIn = @"d:\gate\images\") //d:\gate\images\ as default path
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    FileStream stream = new FileStream(searchIn + @"\" + id + ".jpg", 
                 System.IO.FileMode.Open);
    response.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = 
                 new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
    return response;
}
```

And you can call this like:

```
Get GetImageFile/myfileId?searchIn=c:\pub //P.S. Don't forget about URL encoding and security
```